# On linux mint start : Press c to stop all check in process

Tags: linux-mint

On linux mint 17.1 Rebica start, I get the following messages:

> Press c to stop all check in process.

Then after some time I am getting:

> press f to fix internal errors, i ignore, s to skip mounting, m for manual recovery.

what is causing these?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site about programming -- that is, writing software. This question is outside that topic.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when upon a startup, a process takes too long, or waits for completion...
at the time you see this message, try to hit Esc, to see the actual console log to determine which process is taking that long, or eventually failing, and try to later fix it..

also investigate the output of `dmesg` for errors

From the second message it seems you need to run `fsck` on your disk .. that should still be shown in the kernel or dmesg logs.

Comment: on fsck running getting this message : fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.



WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>?

Comment: you should avoid fsck on a mounted filesystem, but you still have the risky option to continue.. so use common sense.